# MySQL ERROR 2013 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, iis-7, mysql-error-2013

I'm trying to import a large database (the .sql file is 300MB) on a local MySQL install, it imports for about two seconds then I get this error message:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 457: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Apparently this is a fairly common error message, but I've tried various different things (all of which haven't solved my problem)

Lots of people reference a `my.cnf` / `my.ini` configuration file which needs editing, the problem is I couldn't for the life of me find this file, I found various `.ini` files in this directory:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5
```

But none were entitled `my.ini`, so (I'm not sure if this is correct) I simply created a my.ini and my.cnf file and put them in the directory above, the contents of this file are as follows:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 400M
innodb_force_recovery = 4
net_read_timeout = 100
interactive_timeout = 100
wait_timeout = 100
connect_timeout = 100
skip-name-resolve

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 400M
```

Firstly, I'm not sure where the configuration file is actually located (I've tried searching my computer for `my.ini` and `my.cnf`, both to no avail) so is there any way to find that?

Secondly, could the issue be at all unrelated to settings in the configuration file? Is there anything else that could be causing this?

Some background info:

- The Database I'm trying to restore is a Magento database
- I'm running it on IIS7 (don't think this is relevant as the problem is with MySQL though)
- the MySQL version is 5.5

I've tried importing the database with MySQL workbench and with SQLyog community edition, but they both fail at just about the same place (I think SQLyog failed about 2 lines earlier/later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I re-installed MySQL, and that alone seemed to solve the problem (very strange!)

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried everything else, timeouts, but the restore was failing at different places every time, sometimes after 60 seconds and sometimes after two minutes.  I got `ERROR 2013 (HY000)` every time. My background was a power outage and probably some corrupt mysql (percona) files, on _linux_ :-).  Reinstalling mysql (`apt-get --purge remove` followed by the standard installation) got me past this issue.  Thanks!!

Comment: Glad this helped someone :) the old adage of "turn it off and on again" (or in this case, reinstall it again!) Seems to work quite well sometimes!